# MongoDB querying from Aggregation to Group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this following query in MongoDB:

```
var subquery = {"shipdate" : { 
"$gte" : 19960101, 
"$lt" : 19960401 } 
};
var eachsupp = db.lineitems.aggregate([
{ $match : subquery },
{ $project : {
    "_id" : 0,
    "revenue" : {$multiply : ["$extendedprice", {$subtract : [1, "$discount"] }] },
    "supplier_no" : "$partsupp.supplier.suppkey",
    "name" : "$partsupp.supplier.name",
    "address" : "$partsupp.supplier.address",
    "phone" : "$partsupp.supplier.phone" }},
{ $group : {
    _id : "$supplier_no",
    total_revenue : { $sum : "$revenue" },
    name : {$first : "$name"},
    address : {$first : "$address"},
    phone : {$first : "$phone"} }}
]);
eachsupp.forEach(function(document){db.tmp.insert(document)});
db.tmp.find().sort({total_revenue : -1}).limit(1);
```

But for academical purposes I need this query using `.group()`. Something like this

```
db.lineitems.group(...);
```

I'm starting like this but I don't know how to go with the next step

```
var red = function(doc, out){
out.supplier_no
out.revenue_calc = doc.extendedprice*(1-doc.discount);
};

db.lineitems.group({
key : "revenue",
cond : subquery,
initial : {revenue_calc : 0},
reduce : red,
finalize : fin
});
```

Comment: Don't bother. You never need or even should run JavaScript evaluation unless the document structure "demands" it. If you have a working aggregation pipeline, then that means there is no need for running a `.group()`. Also, any case where the document structure actually "needs" JavaScript processing is usually a good indicator that the structure should be changed. Anyone paying attention to various changes in the MongoDB core server code, would see good indicators that JavaScript is slowly but surely on the way out.

Comment: I know that but for other purposes I need this solution with the .group(). It's not to be fast or better. I just need. Can you help me in my .group()